# Getting a scrollviewer to stretch until maxwidth

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a scrollviewer which isn't stretching to fit its content up until maxwidth. Currently, it sets the width to the MinWidth value... and that's about it.

This is the code I'm using, I've tried both with and without HorizontalAlignment="Stretch".

```
<Border BorderBrush="#5D5D5D" BorderThickness="5" Padding="0" Height="75"  Background="White">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" MaxWidth="800" MinWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}" >
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Comment: Try `HorizontalContentAlignment` to Stretch

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm afraid it doesn't work.

Comment: Share more of your layout or a generic one to reproduce the issue, your culprit likely lies in your layout elsewhere.

Comment: That actually is a generic one I made on a separate blank project to try to isolate the issue. That inside a blank page, filling the itemscontrol with textblocks is enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: So that's the only thing on a new page? Is the Border and ScrollViewer like that? Interesting, Throw it in a panel like a Grid and see what's actually not stretching, the Border, the ScrollViewer, or the ItemsControl. Your HorizontalContentAlignment may be on the wrong thing.

Comment: Yup, exactly like that. If I remove the ScrollViewer, the border and itemscontrol stretch to fit all the content. I tried putting the HorizontalContentAlignment on the ItemsControl, but that did nothing and it stretches anyway. I guess it is the ScrollViewer which is acting up.

Comment: Looks fine to me, except that the Border isn't constrained by the ScrollViewer's MaxWidth, so the ScrollViewer becomes centered within the wider border once the available width exceeds 800.  Try moving MinWidth and MaxWidth to the Border, and you can also get rid of `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`, as that is the default.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Interestingly, when I do that the ScrollViewer gets a width of 0, it's not stretching to accommodate the content at all.

Comment: @LucasCordina That doesn't match my test.  I moved my comment to an answer so I could attach a screenshot.

Comment: OMG this is infuriating. VerticalAlignment="Stretch" results in a height of 150 out of an available 359. Yet again xaml syntax is confusing as hell. So what exactly does "Stretch" do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine to me, except that the `Border` isn't constrained by the `MaxWidth` of the `ScrollViewer`, so the `ScrollViewer` becomes centered within the wider `Border` once the available width exceeds `800`.

Try moving `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` to the `Border`.

This is what the result looks like for me, with the `MaxWidth` reduced to `400` for a smaller screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the `Border` will grow horizontally up to `MaxWidth`.  When the window is shrunken, the `Border` will be reduced in width until it hits `200`.

I added the `ItemTemplate` so you could see the bounds of the items within the `ItemsControl`; the sizing behavior is unchanged if you comment it out.